# Understanding koan 121

Tags: ruby

I'm working through the Ruby koans (again) and I'm up to 121 (again).

I've solved it, but there are several things I don't understand. Here's the relevant koan code:

```
def my_private_method
    "a secret"
  end
  private :my_private_method

  def test_calling_private_methods_without_receiver
    assert_equal "a secret", my_private_method
  end

  def test_calling_private_methods_with_an_explicit_receiver
    exception = assert_raise(NoMethodError) do
      self.my_private_method
    end
    assert_match /__/, exception.message
  end
```

It turns out if I replace the double underscore on the second-to-last line with `my_private_method` it passes; So `exception.message` is a match for the name of the non-method, I'm guessing. I can also just delete the underscores, but I don't think that is the point of the lesson.

I THINK `self.my_private_method` throws a NoMethodError and this gets assigned to exception. From another online tutorial, I know that private methods can't be called with self, so I assume THAT's the point.

But, the `my_private_method` doesn't appear to be private, unless that `private :my_private_method` makes it so. Is that what's happening? (And if so, I will despair yet again at Ruby's indecision at how things should be done, and at the ability of symbols to do, seemingly, anything).

So, again, my question is: what does `private :my_private_method` do?

Comment: When learning a language there will always be things that don't make sense until you've learned to think in that language. That's true of spoken, and computer, languages. Rather than criticize how a language's designers defined it, because you don't understand yet, just accept it. Criticizing it doesn't make the language seem bad to those of us who use it, it just makes you sound impatient and lacking understanding. I wound my way to Ruby via many other languages, and in comparison to those others I find Ruby very well thought out.

Comment: I agree I'm still relatively ignorant of the language. But Ruby was routinely introduced as 'easy to learn' and that's not the case so, yes, I am frustrated and impatient that it's taking so long to pick up. I'll try to refrain from venting in my questions.

Comment: `'easy to learn'` for who? Every programmer thinks differently, so "easy" for one is not necessarily easy for another. That's why there are different languages, because someone couldn't grok one thing and wanted to invent their own wheel because they figured they could do it better. And, some languages do some things more easily than another; Knowing multiple languages should give us the insight into which one to pick for a certain job. Stick with Ruby though. I think you'll come to like its foibles and Matz' opinions on how things should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, again, my question is: what does `private :my_private_method` do?

`private` is actually just a regular method, defined on `Module`, [`Module#private`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-private).

From [the documentation for that method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-private) (emphasis mine):

> #### `private` → `self`
>
> #### `private(symbol, ...)` → `self`
>
> #### `private(string, ...)` → `self`
>
> With no arguments, sets the default visibility for subsequently
>   defined methods to private. **With arguments, sets the named methods to
>   have private visibility.** String arguments are converted to symbols.
>
> ```
> module Mod
>   def a()  end
>   def b()  end
>   private
>   def c()  end
>   private :a
> end
> Mod.private_instance_methods   #=> [:a, :c]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Symbols do nothing. They are just data. Like strings. Or numbers. Methods do something. In particular, the `private` method makes a method private. The `attr_accessor` method creates two methods. And so on.

> So, again, my question is: what does `private :my_private_method` do?

It calls the method `private` passing `:my_private_method` as the argument. And if you look up the documentation of `private`, it tells you that it makes the method whose name matches the symbol private.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the `private` = method thing. Surely there's SOME kind of 'magic' going on the background regarding symbols; It seems like they're easily interpreted as OTHER things: instance variables when used with `attr_accessor` and here, apparently, methods when used with `private`. It seems a bit obfuscated to me. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: Well, and numbers are sometimes interpreted as lengths, and sometimes as ages, and sometimes as times, but that doesn't confuse you, does it? Strings are sometimes interpreted as names, sometimes as streets, sometimes as cities, sometimes as countries, sometimes as novels, sometimes as poems. If it makes you feel better, almost all methods that take symbols as arguments also take strings instead.

Comment: The obfuscation is in the method code (eg, the code for `private`) I guess. I'm used to strict typing so it's odd (outside of the hidden methods) to see symbols equate to instance variables or method names. To use your analogy - I'm not used to using a 'String' novel as a 'Number' time.

Comment: What other datatype would you use for the name of a method, then? Java uses strings for method names, C# uses strings for method names, Smalltalk uses strings for method names, … Note that symbols *do not* equate to instance variables. Not ever. A symbol only ever equates to itself. It may be used to *represent* the *name* of an instance variable. But that's normal: after all, symbols are supposed to represent unique names. That's their purpose.

Comment: I've not had to pass method NAMES around before. I would as a call back, but that's the actual method which is of the type Function. I'm just getting used to the 'looseness' of Ruby, is all. I'm a bit frustrated at having to learn what seems like 3 times the syntax because they've included every idea they've encountered. When you see some code you don't recognise you assume it's something new, but often it's just an alternate way to do something you already know.

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    # some amazing things that bar does
  end
  private :bar
end
```

It's the same thing if you would write:

```
class Foo

  private

  def bar
    # ...
  end
end
```

It's just different syntax with same effect.

Comment: You mean `private :bar`, not `private :foo`, right?